# Meaning&Computation of range property in CMAPI map.view.zoom message

Tags: convert, scale, zoom, luciadmap

We are implementing a [CMAPI 1.3.0](http://cmapi.org/versions/v1.3.0/docs/) programming interface to abstract basic Gis commands from the actual Gis library underneath (Luciad Lightspeed 2016.0).

In the [map.view.zoom](http://cmapi.org/versions/v1.3.0/docs/index.html#map.view.zoom) command, I don't understand the meaning of the *range* parameter. I posted [this message](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/common-map-widget-api/zoom/common-map-widget-api/DjyIA0kUO1s/XUglTEJbJAAJ) to the official discussion group. It's been a while now and nothing came out of it (yet).
For those who can't read the question, I wanted to emphasis the following post:

> Is there a formula for how "camera height above earth's surface" can
>   be calculated from the map scale?
>
> The closest I have found is this article
>   (https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/02/25/map-viewing-altitude/)
>   that explains that "the altitude depends on the map’s scale and then
>   on your viewing distance away from the center of the map". As it does
>   not make sense have the definition of the map zoom depend on your
>   current viewing distance from the screen, it would be nice if someone
>   can clarify how the CMAPI zoom property relates to map scale.

Does anybody knows how to convert *Map Scale* to/from *CMAPI range*?

Answer (score 1):

The description for the `range` parameter in the CMAPI `map.view.zoom` message was updated on May 9, 2016 to read:

> The distance in meters from the map. For a 2D map this may be
>   translated to the closest zoom level. For a 3D map it should be
>   interpreted as the camera's distance in meters from the center of the
>   map - which is essentially the camera's altitude when looking straight
>   down.

According to this I interpret `range` to equal zoom level if 2D-map. They have not defined "zoom level", but most map engines use a int value from 0 and up. The Open Street Map wiki provides a overview of how to convert from zoom level to scale and/or resolution: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Resolution_and_Scale